# IntelliJ - Is there a way to move the SceneBuilder to the right side of the IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

When I'm building the layout with IntelliJ using FXML, the layout can be viewed by using the SceneBuilder in another tab.

[image]

Is there a way to make it so the FXML code and scenebuilder can both be viewed at the sametime so I don't have to keep alternating back and forth between the two panels Text and SceneBuilder?

In Android studio the equivalent of the SceneBuilder would be the Preview which is located all the way on the right side of the IDE.

[image]

How can I move the SceneBuilder all the way to the right like so? Or is there something else that is used to preview the layout that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display, within Intellij Idea, both the fxml source view and the SceneBuilder view at the same time, for the same FXML file:

1. Double click the FXML file in the Project Pane to open it.
2. Right-click on the tab header of the FXML file.
3. Choose "Split Right" or "Split Down" depending on your preference.

- You will now have two tabs for the same FXML file, both showing the FXML source.

4. In your second tab for the FXML file, click on "Scene Builder" in the bottom tab.

- You will now have your source FXML and the Scene Builder FXML for the same file side by side.

5. (optional extra) If you want a source view or Scene Builder view in a new window rather than a new tab, right-click the related tab header and choose "Move to tab to New Window".

[image: screenshot]

*Unrelated aside*

For me, on a Mac OS (10.15), Scene Builder inside IntelliJ (2021.2 UE) shows garbled fonts throughout the application making it unusable (the stand-alone SceneBuilder app from Gluon does not have this issue).  Hopefully, it works better for you.

- Intellij bug tracker link for the unusable fonts in SceneBuilder on Mac when embedded in Idea [IDEA-266524](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-266524).

So, this is a known issue which Intellij will hopefully address in a future release.

Comment: This works but the only issue is that when you make an edit to something in the split screen fxml it isn't reflected on the scenebuilder until you click on the text tab and reclick on the scenebuilder tab

Comment: SceneBuilder isn't really usable for me with my current configuration so I can't offer any additional advice.  I know for the standalone Scene Builder, changes to the UI aren't reflected in the FXML source until you save the change in Scene Builder, but I don't know if the embedded Scene Builder inside Idea works the same way.  I suggest you contact Intellij support directly with questions and concerns about their product, though they do appear to offer some level of support for StackOverflow questions, so maybe they might be able to help yo.

Comment: Also, I know that, if you externally edit an FXML file in Idea, the standalone SceneBuilder will automatically pick up the changes (you don't have to execute a manual save operation in Idea for this to occur, just refocus on the standalone SceneBuilder application).  Again, I don't know if this behavior carries over to the embedded SceneBuilder in Idea.

Comment: it's not picking picking up the changes for me in idea :/

https://i.imgur.com/F14o5LH.mp4 unless i click on the text tab and reclick scenebuilder tab

Comment: You can submit a feature request for Idea using the [the intellij youtrack web-based issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).